# memcache and memcache java client

Tags: memcached

how to use java memcache client now after memcache server is up and connect to my java application..- any help?

Comment: Note that "memcache and memcache java client" is not a question.  It's far more efficient to ask google which will quickly lead you to [examples](http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/wiki/Examples) in [my client](http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/).

Comment: This is a perfect example for "How **not** to ask a question".

Answer (score 1):

it worked..corrected  the path for memcached jar file.